# Do action after user click the notification OK message in MobileFirst app?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

do action after user click the notification OK message in Mobile First app?

My Notification should be go to new page "html page" after users click the notification center message entering the app.

But where should my code be ? in Handler function or what ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0kYz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the handler function of the SimpleDialog to navigate to another area in your application.